# Embed Windows form panel in WPF control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, designmode, elementhost

I'm trying to design fancy WPF controls for Windows desktop application.
I'm wondering if it is possible to expose an embedded panel in a WPF control.
The idea is to create a panel with a entitled ribbon. A button will be used to deploy or hide contained controls.

Here is my new panel :

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestRibbonPanel.RibbonPanel.XamlRibbonPanel"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms" 
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestRibbonPanel.RibbonPanel"
mc:Ignorable="d" 
d:DesignHeight="150" d:DesignWidth="200" MinHeight="40" x:Name="uc">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:BorderHeightConverter x:Key="BhConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Background="Transparent">
    <Grid x:Name="grd" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="btn" Background="#333333" Click="Btn_Click"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="Title" Background="#333333" Foreground="#CCCCCC"/>
    </Grid>
    <Popup x:Name="pu" StaysOpen="True" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=grd}" AllowsTransparency="True" PopupAnimation="Slide" IsOpen="True">
        <Border x:Name="brd" Background="White" CornerRadius="0,0,10,10" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=uc, Converter={StaticResource BhConverter}, FallbackValue=130}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=grd, FallbackValue=200}" SizeChanged="Brd_SizeChanged">
            <WindowsFormsHost>
                <wf:Panel x:Name="pnl" BorderStyle="FixedSingle" BackColor="Red"/>
            </WindowsFormsHost>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

In the code behind, i have used a System.Windows.Controls.Panel as a property named ContentPanel :

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace TestRibbonPanel.RibbonPanel
{
/// <summary>
/// Logique d'interaction pour XamlRibbonPanel.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class XamlRibbonPanel : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsOPenProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsOpen", typeof(bool), typeof(XamlRibbonPanel), new PropertyMetadata(true));
    public bool IsOPen
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsOPenProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IsOPenProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public System.Windows.Forms.Panel ContentPanel
    {
        get { return pnl; }
    }

    public XamlRibbonPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Brd_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        pnl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size((int)brd.ActualWidth, (int)brd.ActualHeight);
    }

    private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        pu.IsOpen = !pu.IsOpen;
    }
}

public class BorderHeightConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (double)value - 20;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    }
}
```

Now i put this WPF control in a windows form wrapper using ElementHost integration class named EH embedding the XamlRibbonPanel control.:

```
    [DesignerAttribute(typeof(XRibbonPanelDesigner))]
public class XRibbonPanel : UserControl
{
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer _components = null;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost EH;
    private RibbonPanel.XamlRibbonPanel _xp = null;
    private Panel _contentPanel = null;

    public Panel ContentPanel
    {
        get { return _contentPanel; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// .ctor
    /// </summary>
    public XRibbonPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _contentPanel = xp.ContentPanel;
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.EH = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost();
        this._xp = new TestRibbonPanel.RibbonPanel.XamlRibbonPanel();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // EH
        // 
        this.EH.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.EH.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.EH.Name = "EH";
        this.EH.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 150);
        this.EH.TabIndex = 0;
        this.EH.Text = "";
        this.EH.Child = _xp;
        // 
        // XRibbonPanel
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.Controls.Add(this.EH);
        this.Name = "XRibbonPanel";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (_components != null))
        {
            _components.Dispose();
        }
        EH.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

As you can see, i have used a custom designer for the control in the hope of exposing the control to design. It's a technique i have read here and successfully applied for other 'classic' controls :

```
    using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

namespace TestRibbonPanel
{
    public class XRibbonPanelDesigner : ScrollableControlDesigner
    {
        XRibbonPanel _panel;
        public override void Initialize(IComponent component)
        {
            base.Initialize(component);
            _panel = (XRibbonPanel)component;

            if (_panel == null)
                throw new ArgumentException();
            else
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.Panel pnl = _panel.ContentPanel;
                if (pnl != null)
                {
                    bool result = EnableDesignMode(pnl, "Layout");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When i put a XRibbonPanel on a form, the panel act as desired (opening and closing panel). But unfortunally, i can't see the 'Layout' object that i usually use to drop off nested controls.
Another annoying effect, when i move the form, the popup Xaml Control float on the desktop dissociated from the original form. It also happen in design mode when i leave the form tab open for instance.

If i set a breakpoint on :

```
bool result = EnableDesignMode(pnl, "Layout");
```

in the designer, pnl is not null and the boolean result is true.

Any clue ?

Comment: The fact that it does not follow the form is the normal behavior. It will happen in a full WPF window. The usual hack to keep it following is to detect the movlent and close/open the popup control.

Comment: You say that it's the behavior of the popup control, okay even if i don't see the point. I choose it because it was more simple than developing a full control to do the same, it seems that i was wrong. However, if i carry on giving it a try, how to i manage to track the movement especially at design time ? In concern of the first question (to know if i can capture the container), nobody have any clue, because if it's not possible i will leave it after all.